# c++: Function taking objects with specific traits

Tags: c++, function, templates, generic-programming

I have a function, that finds the shortest path between two nodes. Right now I use the following node class:

```
struct SConnection
{
    SConnection(CNode *To, unsigned int Distance);
    CNode *To;
    unsigned int Distance;
};

class CNode
{
public:
    CNode();

    std::vector<SConnection> Connections()const;

    bool AddConnection(CNode *mTo, unsigned int nDistance);
    bool AddConnection(const SConnection &mConnection);
    bool RemoveConnection(CNode *mTo);

    CNode* Addr();

    bool Completed = false;
    CNode *PreviousNode = 0;
    unsigned int XPos = 0;
    unsigned int YPos = 0;

private:
    std::vector<SConnection> m_vConnections;
};
```

If want to make this function more generic, how exactly should I do it? Taking a `template` instead of an instance of `CNode` is obvious. But other classes might not have functions and members called exactly like in `CNode`. Passing function pointers would work, but I doubt that is the "modern" solution for this.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    int a;
};

int HelperFunction(SomeClass obj)
{
    return obj.a;
}

template<typename T>
void MyGenericFunction(T obj, int(*FunctionToGetSomeValue)(T))
{
    int ValueINeed = (*FunctionToGetSomeValue)(obj);
}

//Calling the function
SomeClass x;

MyGenericFunction(x, HelperFunction);
```

I think there are better ways to do this, right?

Comment: Instead of `obj` and pointer to function you can pass `std::bind` object, or any other callable obj (lambda), that will return ValueYouNeed.

Comment: Two questions
1. What version of c++ can you use? c++98, 11, 14, 17 ?
2. What are you trying to achieve. It does not make sense to create a generic function just because you can. I recommend to not go with generics at first and when you have a use-case where making the function generic improves the logic then you can think about it.

Comment: @balki I can use c++14. The Code works so making it more generic is the last step. I want this function to work with any object as long as this obj has the members I need for the function.